# Is there a good way to implement RealityKit into a Swift playground?

Tags: swift, augmented-reality, arkit, realitykit, reality-composer

I want to be able to add a file created in Reality Composer into a Swift Playground for testing purposes.  I also think it would be interesting to use as a supplement to a playbook.  How would one go about adding an rcproject into a playground like the Experience.rcproject Apple provides with the scene “Box”?

Answer (score 5):

> You can read a `.reality` file format in Playground using the following code:

```
import Cocoa
import RealityKit
import PlaygroundSupport

let arView = ARView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 800, height: 200))
arView.environment.background = .color(.black)
        
let fileURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "main", withExtension: "reality")
let bowlingScene = try! Entity.load(contentsOf: fileURL!)
        
let anchor = AnchorEntity()
anchor.addChild(bowlingScene)
anchor.scale = [4,4,4]
anchor.position.y = -0.5

arView.scene.anchors.append(anchor)

PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = arView
```

> So, supply a `.playground` file with a `main.reality` scene, making it nested.

[image]

---

About **Swift Playgrounds** for iPad [read here](https://medium.com/@arkit/realitykit-911-swift-playgrounds-or-how-to-create-and-debug-ar-apps-on-ipad-pro-190a6d2e03bb).

---

Comment: You can change the bowlingScene with any entity you want. Not necessarily from a .reality file.

Comment: Totally agree. However Apple engineers left a tip in Xcode console – we have to use a `.reality` file with a name `main`. `.reality` files work faster in playground.

Comment: Saw the tip, from my expirience it works perfectly fine with entities you create in the code